# Wireless Network Bandwith Control

Tags: wifi, bandwidth-control

I have a client who would like to setup public wifi in their waiting rooms.  They had a solution, but invariably someone would take up so much bandwidth it would start causing issues with their VOIP.

I'm trying to set up a new system, and in my test lab I've had no luck with keeping my test laptops on the WIFI from being able to use up all the available bandwidth.

I've tried the QOS in the adtran router, I installed dd-wrt onto a linksys access point and setup TC qdisc/class/filters, I've tried the bandwidth limit on a tenda wifi router.  And I tried using the qos on a cisco soho 91.

I feel like I've tried everything but can't get a hard limit on bandwidth usage.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the same problem.  I have a "client area" that has unlocked wifi.  We are using Sonicwall Pro3060s and this allows us to set the ingress and egress of the WAN port.  Then in the firewall setup for the outbound traffic, you can tell the rules to only allow a certain percentage of the WAN ports bandwidth based on source (subnet, firewall port, IP etc).  Works nicely and keeps the clients from chewing up our entire 100Mbps pipe.

I do the same traffic shaping for internal outbound traffic too and limit each subnet to a max of 25% which keeps each department from stepping on the others.

Answer (score 0):

I limit this by having a DD-WRT Linksys router setup to provide our corporate WLAN, and a public WLAN. They are divided into two VLAN's.

The corporate VLAN is routed straight through to the rest of the network, where DNS/DHCP are handled by servers.

The Public VLAN uses the router as DHCP/DNS, and the router is limited to 1024kbs in the QoS settings. The router cannot pass anything faster than 1024kbs, yet since our corporate VLAN is routed straight through it to and leaves the network via another router, it's not affected by the QoS.